# Compute similarity between columns in a fast manner MATLAB

Tags: matlab, similarity

Given a (rather) big matrix A :

```
 A [m*n] (m = 7, n = 15000)
```

where the columns are items and the rows are attributes, I would like to compute similarity between each two items and store it in an array. The similarity matrix could be `sim` where each row contains `[item1_id,item2_id, similarity]`. This process needs to be done very fast.

I am considering options like *@bsxfun* which uses multi-threading for this purpose. Others ideas are also similarly appreciated (I am totally open to  other efficient approaches). It would be appreciated if you could suggest some approaches and report the timing it takes for you to perform the operation. This process may be scaled up in future.
 Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you define the similarity between two rows? Maybe use `pdist`?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I forgot to mention this, the similarity is the cosine similarity between two vectors (columns)

Comment: Use `pdist`, be careful it calculates the cosine distance, not the similarity, take 1-result for similarity.

Comment: If it has to be "very fast" consider coding it in C and compiling it as an external application.

Comment: @BlackAdder: That is not a useful suggestion, `pdist` is implemented using native code and I have serious doubts anyone here is able to beat that implementation in performance significantly.

Comment: Isn't this just a covariance matrix? Normalize the columns and then do `A' * A`.

Comment: @Daniel: I think also using `pdist` is the best option. It is really fast an efficient.
@BlackAdder: I agree with Daniel's comment.
@ Anon: It works as well. However, it is not extendable for using other types of similarity metric. `pdist` was exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: Daniel, out of curiosity may I know how could we realize a code is written in naive code so we can consider for fast applications? My point of reference is to codes written in MATLAB. Thanks